# How to save path and return to it with Ember's V2 Router

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

So, I'm having some issues with Ember's new router. I'm trying to save and later return to the current path for a given dynamic segment, so my urls might look like

```
#/inventory/vehicle/1001
```

Which can then branch off into

```
#/inventory/vehicle/1001/details
#/inventory/vehicle/1001/photos
#/inventory/vehicle/1001/description
```

etc. I need a way to return to the most recent route. The Ember guides have a method for this here:

http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/redirection/

The problem with this method is that by creating the "/choose" route and assigning it to "/", this overwrites the standard "/inventory/vehicle/1001" route. For instance, if I were to try to create a linkTo a vehicle like so:

```
{{#linkTo "vehicle" vehicle}}
```

Then Ember will throw an error because the "vehicle" route no longer exists. Instead, it must be set to:

```
{{#linkTo "vehicle.choose" vehicle}}
```

Which works, activates the VehicleChooseRoute and everything. Except, since "vehicle.choose" is technically a child of "vehicle", the #linkTo ONLY has an active class applied when the current route is

```
#/inventory/vehicle/1001
```

Which instantaneously redirects to the latest filter, and so it's basically never on. So basically I'm trying to figure out a way around this. I tried changing the path of "vehicle.choose" to be the standard path (#/inventory/vehicle/1001/choose) so it doesn't overwrite the "vehicle" route, and then setting up VehicleRoute like so:

```
Case.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('inventory', function(){
    this.route('review');
    this.route('sheets');
    this.resource('vehicle', { path: '/vehicle/:vehicle_id' }, function(){
      this.route('choose');
      this.route('details');
      this.route('consignor');
      this.route('additional');
      this.route('price');
      this.route('dmv');
      this.route('expenses');
      this.route('description');
      this.route('tasks');
    });
  });
});

App.VehicleRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return Case.Vehicle.find(params.vehicle_id);
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    model.set('active', true);
  },
  redirect: function() {
    this.transitionTo('vehicle.choose');
  }
})

Case.VehicleChooseRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function() {
    var lastFilter = this.controllerFor('vehicle').get('lastFilter');
    this.transitionTo('vehicle.' + (lastFilter || 'details'));
  }
});
```

But the problem that arises from this (aside from feeling rather hacked together) is that redirect replaces the entire template that would normally be rendered by "vehicle" so I only get the subview. So that's not an option.